# Merge and sort two Parse object arrays

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I have two arrays which are of different Parse classes. They both have the same field `createdDate`. Is it possible to query them individually and then merge them together, ordered by `createdDate`?

Answer (score 4):

I assume you are getting two resulting arrays, rather than two objects right? Otherwise you could just compare the two objects by their`created_date` field. So if you get query result as two arrays, you can [`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) them, then do a [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) by a custom comparison function. Like so:

```js
var queryFromParse1 = function () {
    return [{name: 'obj1', created_date: new Date('2014-10-10')}];
};

var queryFromParse2 = function () {
    return [{name: 'obj2', created_date: new Date('2012-10-10')}];
};

var array1 = queryFromParse1();
var array2 = queryFromParse2();
var sorted = array1.concat(array2).sort(function (a, b) {
    // For real parse object, you need to do a.get('createdAt')
    return a.created_date.getTime() - b.created_date.getTime();
});

console.log(sorted[0].name);
console.log(sorted[1].name);

// this prints out obj2, obj1
```

In real life your `queryFromParse1` and `queryFromParse2` would be how the results are queried.

The trick of the comparison function here is that [`Date.getTime()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) returns you the number of milliseconds since `1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC`. And the way the comparison function indicates result is:

- negative means first < second
- 0 means first === second
- positive means first > second